# React-router stops working when error boundary catches an error in route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-error-boundary

The codepen linked to below, uses `react-router` and an error boundary to catch errors within each route.

If you click on "Shop", the error is caught as expected, *but* the other links then no longer works. What's going on here? Why does `react-router-dom` seemingly stop working? What is the "correct" way to do this? Is it a problem with the `<ErrorBoundary>` component, or the way the route components are wrapped, or?

https://codepen.io/mpontus/pen/NyKNoL

---

In case something happens to the codepen link:

```
const { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, NavLink } = ReactRouterDOM;

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = { hasError: false };

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>An error has occured.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

const HomeScreen = () => <h3>Home</h3>;

const ProfileScreen = () => <h3>Profile Screen</h3>;

const ShopScreen = () => {
  throw new Error("Error during render");
};

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="container">
      <nav className="nav nav-pills">
        <NavLink exact className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" to="/">
          Home
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" to="/profile">
          Profile
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" to="/shop">
          Shop
        </NavLink>
      </nav>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={() => (
            <ErrorBoundary>
              <HomeScreen />
            </ErrorBoundary>
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/profile"
          render={() => (
            <ErrorBoundary>
              <ProfileScreen />
            </ErrorBoundary>
          )}
        />
        <Route
          path="/shop"
          render={() => (
            <ErrorBoundary>
              <ShopScreen />
            </ErrorBoundary>
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, since you're reusing the `ErrorBoundary` for each route, it's never unmounted (this is by design). As such, its `hasError` state persists across each route.

You can mitigate this by updating the state when the location changes within the `ErrorBoundary` component:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname) {
      this.setState({ hasError: false });
    }
  }
```

Since you're using the `render` prop, you'll have to manually pass the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) to the `ErrorBoundary` component:

For example:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  render={props => (
    <ErrorBoundary {...props}>
      <HomeScreen {...props} />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  )}
/>
```

---

**Working demo** (since this codesandbox is in `development`, it'll show an error overlay, so you'll have to close the error window to continue):

[image: Edit Error Boundary]

Answer (score 0):

for the record, I think if you don't want to have issue of error state remain after changing route & define error boundary on each route in r.r v6, you can solve it like below:

a: define variable to save prev location:

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
        this.prevPath = null;
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { error: true, errorInfo: error };
  }
```

b: set current location on component did mount

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.prevPath = window.location.pathname;
  }
```

c: and finally did update should be like this:

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (window.location.pathname !== this.prevPath)
      this.setState({ error: null, errorInfo: null });
    this.prevPath = window.location.pathname;
  }
```

d: wrap outlet like this:

```
  <ErrorBoundry>
    <Outlet />
  </ErrorBoundry>
```